# How to get time in range of two hours no matter which day?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I am using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and its plugin [moment-range](http://gf3.github.io/moment-range/), I want to get time in range of two hours no matter which day.

For example,

- Jan 9, 2014 08:30am
- Jan 1, 2015 10:00am
- Feb 5, 2016 08:30am

Say I want to get between 8am to 9am. The result I want is

- Jan 9, 2014 08:30am
- Feb 5, 2016 08:30am

Can someone give me some hint? Thanks

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(moment.range(start, end))` with a date time type?

Comment: @AKADER because I have to give `start` and `end` exact date, cannot just give hour

Comment: If I don't give, it uses Jan 01 1990 by default

Comment: Ok I see what your saying, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @AKADER it is alright, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `moment.get('hour')` and `moment.get('minute')` of each and do some simple math comparisons

Comment: Oh, that is a good idea, even no need to use `moment-range`, thanks!

Comment: Otherwise have to set dates the same for each one and probably less code to do this

Comment: Using `getHours();` even no need `momentjs`! :)